# how to get user who creates article in blog using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I am writing own blog in ruby on rails. I got stuck while getting user who creates articles on views. Basically I want to fetch username of user who creates article(post) in my blog application.
I have user, article tables where I have user_id in article table. I do not know how to fetch user who create article in application.Basically I want to display name (username) of user who create article on article/index.html page. I tried to get user name while creating article in article controller

```
def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user
      @article.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
```

but could not get.

Currently users_controller.rb is empty.

Do I need join between user and article table or is it possible with out join in rails. Please suggest me.

article/index.html.

```
<div class="">
  <title> <h2> learning experience blog </h2></title>
</div>

<div style="margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 20px 20px 10px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #82b548 ;">

<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div style=" border-bottom: none:border: 1px solid #666666;border-radius: 1px 1px 1px 1px;margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 20px 20px 10px;height:280px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF ">
    <div style="color:#51702E"><h2><%= article.title %></h2></div>
    <div style="color:#666666; margin-top:10px"> <%= article.created_at %></div> 


    <hr style="border: 1px solid #FA9300;">
    <div style="margin-top:10px; color:"> <%= truncate(article.body, :length => 500, :separator => ' ') %></div>  
    <div style="margin-top:35px">
    <% if current_user.try(:is_admin) %>
     <%= link_to "edit",edit_article_path(article), :class => 'btn btn-warning btn' %>
     <%= link_to "delete",article_path(article),:method => :delete,:confirm => 'Are you sure?',:class => 'btn  btn-danger' %>
    <% end %>
     <%= link_to "view more...",article_path(article), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %> 
   </div>
     </div>
    <% end %>
 <% if current_user.try(:is_admin) %>
  <%= link_to "Create new Article", new_article_path, :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user.id
      @article.save
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy
      redirect_to action:  'index'  
    end

    def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
     end
end
```

user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
    has_many :comments
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
   attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

article_rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end
```

schema.rb

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130406120152) do

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.boolean  "is_admin"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "is_active"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

Please suggest me how to get user info who creates article.

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you have the relationships defined in your model.

```
class User
   has_many :articles
end


class Article
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you could simply do

```
a = Article.find_by_id(1)
a.user # to get the user for Article
```

Comment: hi Myth17,thanks for your replyl. but how to use this info in articles_controller.rb and artilce/index.html.erb page. Any idea.

Comment: basically I want to fetch user info regarding article on article/index.html.erb page.

Comment: try: `@users = Article.all.map {|article| article.user}`

Comment: In your Template you could have <%= @article.user %> to show user. Put it inside an 'each' loop for multiple articles in 'index' action.

Comment: hi Zippie, should i try in articles_controller.rb with your suggestion.